# google map api V3 markers

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am having a problem with google maps, I cant put markers on some location. My idea was to find my location and to put marker on it, then to put markers on other locations but the markers on other locations are not showing on a map.

```
function success(position) {
      var mapcanvas = document.createElement('div');
      mapcanvas.id = 'mapcontainer';
      mapcanvas.style.height = '550px';
      mapcanvas.style.width = '960px';

      document.querySelector('article').appendChild(mapcanvas);

      var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

      var options = {
          zoom: 15,
          center: coords,
          mapTypeControl: false,
          navigationControlOptions: {
              style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
          },
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcontainer"), options);

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: coords,
          map: map,
          title: "Vasa lokacija"
      });
  }

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
  } else {
      error('Geo Location is not supported');
  }
  var locations = [
      ['Banja Luka', 44.766666699999990000, 17.183333299999960000, 4],
      ['Tuzla', 44.532841000000000000, 18.670499999999947000, 5],
      ['Zenica', 44.203439200000000000, 17.907743200000027000, 3],
      ['Sarajevo', 43.850000000000000000, 18.250000000000000000, 2],
      ['Mostar', 43.333333300000000000, 17.799999999999954000, 1]
  ];
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var marker, i;

  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
          map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
          return function () {
              infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
          }
      })(marker, i));
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

the main problem with your code is you are plotting the marker before the map is loaded because it is out side of your function `success`.try this:I have use static value for center you can change it as per your code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    success(position);
});

var position = { // suppose this is your position
    coords: {
        latitude: 44.666666699999990000,
        longitude: 17.183333299999960000
    }
};

var map;
var marker, i;

var locations = [
    ['Banja Luka', 44.766666699999990000, 17.183333299999960000, 4],
    ['Tuzla', 44.532841000000000000, 18.670499999999947000, 5],
    ['Zenica', 44.203439200000000000, 17.907743200000027000, 3],
    ['Sarajevo', 43.850000000000000000, 18.250000000000000000, 2],
    ['Mostar', 43.333333300000000000, 17.799999999999954000, 1]
];

function success(position) {
    var mapcanvas = document.createElement('div');
    mapcanvas.id = 'mapcontainer';
    mapcanvas.style.height = '550px';
    mapcanvas.style.width = '960px';
    document.getElementById('article').appendChild(mapcanvas);

    var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

    var options = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: coords,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        navigationControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
        },
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcontainer"), options);

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: coords,
        map: map,
        title: "Vasa lokacija"
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function (marker, i) {

            infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: but it doesnt show my current location, it show other markers but i cant see my location

Comment: i have passed static value you pass you position.

Comment: i have added your position also try now.pass position to success(position).

Comment: Please indent your code properly when posting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your function is that your marker adding loop is outside success function, so it never gets called. You also had an extra `}`at the end of your code. Here is a full solution  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vgnzb9d1/)

```
var map;

function success(position) {

    var mapcanvas = document.createElement('div');
    mapcanvas.id = 'mapcontainer';
    mapcanvas.style.height = '550px';
    mapcanvas.style.width = '960px';

    document.querySelector('article').appendChild(mapcanvas);

    var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

    var options = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: coords,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        navigationControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
        },
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapcontainer"), options);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: coords,
        map: map,
        title: "Vasa lokacija"
    });

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
    } else {
        error('Geo Location is not supported');
    }

    var locations = [
        ['Banja Luka', 44.766666699999990000, 17.183333299999960000, 4],
        ['Tuzla', 44.532841000000000000, 18.670499999999947000, 5],
        ['Zenica', 44.203439200000000000, 17.907743200000027000, 3],
        ['Sarajevo', 43.850000000000000000, 18.250000000000000000, 2],
        ['Mostar', 43.333333300000000000, 17.799999999999954000, 1]
    ];

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {
                infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }

} //success fn ENDS

var position = {
    coords: {
        latitude: 44.766666699999990000,
        longitude: 17.183333299999960000
    }
};

success(position);
```

Comment: use ; after position otherwise it will give syntax error.

Comment: its works, i have only to center map to my position but its easy i guess, thank you codeepic :)

Comment: Please indent your code properly when posting an answer.